# Using a reference as the iterator in for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading the 5th edition of c++ Primer. I come across the following code snippet for which I have the doubt:

```
int num1=2;
int num2=3;
int &ref_num = num1  //Ok, ref_num is a non-constant int type reference to num1
int &ref_num = num2 //Error, as ref_num is already declared in prev statement
```

So, we can not bind reference variable to multiple objects at the same time. But it also says, we can go through a string literal using a reference control variable.

```
string line("Hello");
for(auto &ref_var : line)
```

So, in this case, my reference variable "ref_var" will be bound to each element of the string object "line". How come?

Comment: hint: `ref_var` in a loop is not a single variable.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

The range-based for loop is equivalent to this (pseudocode):

```
for (i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
{
    auto& ref_var = line[i];
    // rest of body here
}
```

In other words, the control variable is actually redeclared each loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks, It's much clearer to me now. So the range-based for loop has a different initialization property compare to a normal for loop. I thought both of them are same.

Comment: And it also says to change any string literals like converting them to uppercase or lowercase, we have to use a reference control variable in range-based for loop, not just any variable. Like for(auto c: line) won't work, but for(auto &c: line) will work. Is there any logical reason behind it?

Comment: @DebasishRayMohapatra imagine changing `auto&` to `auto` in my pseudocode sample , you get a copy of the element instead of a reference to it